# Running module specific tests in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij and I keep running into this problem where the IDE refuses to run module specific tests.

The steps I take are:

1. I drill down into the module to `test/java`
2. I right click on `java` and click `run-all-tests`
3. In the console all I see is "Process finished with exit code 0", and in the left pane that shows the results of each test run, I just see a `<default package>`. I dont see any of the tests.

Has anyone else encountered a problem like this?

When I checkout the code for the first time, it all seems to work. But after using it for a couple of weeks or so I get this problem.

Vivek

Comment: what version of IDEA do you use?

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply! IDEA 12